# jQuery isotope selected/expanded inner hyperlinks

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope

Need help with this one, been cracking my head for days to get it work.

Referring to this demo http://jsfiddle.net/8QkEw/313/, how do I modify my code to enable inner hyperlinks to work while expanded/selected itemSelector stay expanded/selected.

```
$(function(){


  var $container = $('#container'),
      $items = $('.item');

  $container.isotope({
    itemSelector: '.item',
    masonry: {
      columnWidth: 100
    },
    getSortData : {
      selected : function( $item ){
        // sort by selected first, then by original order
        return ($item.hasClass('selected') ? -500 : 0 ) + $item.index();
      }
    },
    sortBy : 'selected'
  })

  $items.click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    // don't proceed if already selected
    var $previousSelected = $('.selected');
    if ( !$this.hasClass('selected') ) {
      $this.addClass('selected');
    }

    $previousSelected.removeClass('selected');

    // update sortData for new items size
    $container
      .isotope( 'updateSortData', $this )
      .isotope( 'updateSortData', $previousSelected )
      .isotope();

  });

});
```

It is only when users click on inner hyperlink will NOT minimize the expanded/selected box; clicking other area will still trigger `$previousSelected.removeClass('selected');`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop event propagation on the links:

```
$('.item a').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Here is a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/VCmNU/

Answer (score 2):

You can add the following handler

```
 $('.item a').click(function(e){
     e.stopPropagation();
 });
```

Working sample [here](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8QkEw/316/).

Comment: thanks guys, appreciated with both solution provided, surely didn't expect it to be so simple. Silly me

Comment: Nothing, I think submitted parallel